# SOC/MiniPC for router

Tags: router, mini-pc

I'm looking for SOC/miniPC to make small home usage router. I'm looking for smthing like that: https://aliexpress.ru/item/32860851243.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.acd74a80odWjAa&algo_pvid=d0a63443-d060-4523-9eef-e2b48b65a663&algo_expid=d0a63443-d060-4523-9eef-e2b48b65a663-2&btsid=0b8b15d416199781020496412e347d&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

But with following requirements:

- One full-size PCI-Express (for Compex WLE600VX wifi card)
- One full-size or half size PCI-Express (for another 2.4Ghz wifi)
- One full-size or half size mSATA/M.2 (for SSD)
- One SATA (for 2.5 HDD)
- 1 Gigabit Ethernet (for WAN)
- ARM/ARM64/x86/x86_64 processor with low TDP

It would be good to have but not required:

- power delivery power input
- 1 COM port
- Second Ethernet (for LAN)

It can have case or it can be just board like RPI.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that banana pi w2 is almost perfect for my purposes.

Comment: Can you tell why it is almost perfect and not perfectly perfect?

Comment: Perfect - has every hardware I need (arm cpu, m.2 interfaces for wifi, at least 2 eth ports), imperfect - there issues with software (poor linux support of soc). So I actually choose banana pi r64 (almost the same, but has better linux suport).